# Blazor login control disappears on phone

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side

Working on new Blazor server-side web site and I started with Visual Studio 2019 template with NavBar down Left-hand side. Placed Login and Register links in upper Right-hand corner of top-row. Everything works fine for desktop browsers but when run on phone the NavBar toggles as it should to the top but the Register and Login links () disappears. I know this is probably a bootstrap thing. Anyone have a solution for this issue?

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4 fixed-top">
        <LoginDisplay />
    </div>
    <CookieConsent />
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Desktop Browsers
[image: Desktop Browser]

Phone Browsers
[image: Phone Browser]

Answer (score 1):

The `.main .top-row` is hidden on less than 767.98px view port with in*wwwroot/css/site.css*:

**site.css**

```css
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .main .top-row {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

So your login component is not displayed

Comment: Commenting the display: none does get the login component to show but then the Navbar is now missing for the phone so you can not navigate the site thru menu. Is there no way to have both for phones?

Comment: Add your Login component to the nav bar with css class hidding it on more than 767.98px view port width

Comment: you can probably use `.navbar-toggler`

Answer (score 0):

I just add the login, logout, and register buttons to the side menu.

In my **/Shared/NavMenu.razor** file, I have this:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        ...
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                    <span style="color:white"> [Logout]</span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </li>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Identity/Account/Login">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> [Login]
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        @if (AllowRegistration)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Identity/Account/Register">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> [Register]
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```